# Play Console - Alerta: una de tus aplicaciones necesita tu intervención

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

Mi aplicación es un botón de alerta, similar a WeHelp, pero adaptada a las necesidades del gobierno de la ciudad donde vivo. La alerta está compuesta por nombre de usuario, y su ubicación. Ésta alerta debe de llegar al número de seguridad a través de SMS ya que es como ellos se coordinan para trabajar.

Pero al momento de subir la aplicación tengo este mensaje:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Desde hace días he intentado subir mi app a la Play Store y ya me la han rechazado 2 veces, me han dicho que no encuentran la funcionalidad principal de la aplicación. Las primeras 2 veces que envié la app recibí este mensaje por e-mail:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La primera vez que me la rechazaron actualicé los permisos a lo que me sugerían los de Google. Y rechazaron la aplicación de igual manera.

Ahora es la tercer vez que envío mi app para que la revisen, **yo sé que a los de Google les puede tomar horas en revisar una app** pero ahora que volví a enviar una nueva versión de la app en el panel de aplicaciones ni siquiera aparece el estado de *"pendiente de publicación"*. Ahora me aparece directamente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora mi pregunta es: **¿Hay un cierto límite de rechazos?**
valoro cualquier aportación.

Comment: Sería importante comentaras que permisos, API´s y si tu aplicación esta definida como aplicación de sistema, ¿que realiza tu aplicación?en base a esto te podría sugerir que modificaciones realizar. Al parecer necesitan una cuenta/password para revisar cierta funcionalidad.

Comment: Hola @Jorgesys ya edité la pregunta.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Google necesita un método de ingreso. Les di un correo y contraseña.